# select the value of dropdownlist yii

Tags: php, yii

I'm using form builder to create the form. I made this code to generate dropdown list, However I am unable to make a desired option selected.

```
'box'=>array(
        'type'=>'dropdownlist',
        'items'=>User::model()->getListUsers(),         
        'prompt'=>'Please select:',
      )
```

I tried with adding one more array key `'select' =>85` to default select the 85 id value but it does not work.

Answer (score 5):

Use the htmlOptions array.

A quick google lead to this example which should help you.

```
$form->dropDownList($model,'sex',array('1'=>'men','2'=>'women'), array('options' => array('2'=>array('selected'=>true))));
```

In your case I'd image you'd need to do

```
'box'=>array(
        'type'=>'dropdownlist',
        'items'=>User::model()->getListUsers(),         
        'prompt'=>'Please select:',
    'htmlOptions'=>array('options' => array(
                        '85'=>array('selected'=>true)
                        )
                );
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Alan

Slightly modification to your answer did the job. Below code worked for me.

```
'box'=>array(
        'type'=>'dropdownlist',
        'items'=>User::model()->getListUsers(),         
        'prompt'=>'Please select:',
        'options' => array('85'=>array('selected'=>true))
      )
```